# How to solve cloud function error with postgresql and cloud sql error relation "table_name" doesnt not exist

Tags: node.js, postgresql, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-sql

I am trying to query a table named "client" of my Cloud SQL database.I am using cloud functions to access Cloud SQL. When I make the query, I get the following error:

```
relation "client" does not exist
```

I want to list all the clients in my table. When I run the same command from `psql` in cloud shell, I get the correct result:

```
postgres=> SELECT * FROM client LIMIT 2 ;
 numcli |    nom    |   prenom   |    ville    |    tel
--------+-----------+------------+-------------+------------
      0 | Ernaut    | Bernadette | marseille   | 0296645394
      1 | Christian | Louis      | montpellier | 0417103362
(2 rows)
postgres=>
```

But the following code in Cloud Functions encounters an error:

```
import * as functions from "firebase-functions";
import * as admin from "firebase-admin";
import * as pg from "pg";

export const sendMoney = functions.https.onCall(async (data, context) => {
  console.log(data);
  if (!context.auth || !context.auth.uid)
    throw new functions.https.HttpsError(
      "unauthenticated",
      "L'action est refusée car aucun utilisateur n'est connecté"
    );

  const pgConfig = {
    max: 1,
    user: "postgres",
    password: "******",
    database: "pay",
    host: "/cloudsql/******:us-central1:****"
  };
  let pgPool;
  if (!pgPool) {
    pgPool = new pg.Pool(pgConfig);
  }
  return pgPool
    .query("SELECT * FROM client LIMIT 2")
    .then(result => {
      console.log(" \n RESULT \n");
      console.log(result);
      };
    })
    .catch(e => {
      console.log(e);
    });
});
```

Comment: Can you post the command you are running from Cloud Shell to get the correct result?

Comment: i run the same command in the cloud shell and the cloud functions. These are the results 
postgres=> SELECT * FROM client LIMIT 2 ;

Comment: Is it possible that you've accidentally connected to the wrong database? What commands do you use to connect? What are the results of `SELECT table_name FROM information_schema.tables WHERE table_schema='public'` from inside the function?

Comment: @kurtisvg I just realized that I was connecting to a database that did not contain any tables or data. When I run the command in cloud shell, by default the command is started on the postgres database. That's why it worked.
And in cloud functions I connected to a database called "test", which contained nothing.Thanks for the help

Comment: No problem! Please make sure to mark your answer as accepted to help other users resolve the issue more quickly in the future.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was I was connecting to the default database (`postgres`) when connecting from Cloud Shell. 
When connecting from Cloud Functions, I was connecting to the `pay` database, which didn't have any tables.

I updated this config:

```
  const pgConfig = {
        max: 1,
        user: "postgres",
        password: "******",
        database: "pay",
        host: "/cloudsql/******:us-central1:****"
      };
```

To connect to the "default" database instead:

```
const pgConfig = {
    max: 1,
    user: "postgres",
    password: "******",
    database: "postgres",
    host: "/cloudsql/******:us-central1:****"
  };
```

And then everything worked correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Confirm the data: 
SELECT * FROM name--;
Check url for any doubt about how to connect to cloud SQL.
https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/quickstart